# How to remove a embedded document from array when the document status is set to false in mognoose

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose

I am seriously looking for a solution to this problem about mongoose.
I am using Express, Mongoose and Graphql.

First of all, I have a user and group collection as below.

```
user {
  name: string,
  groupAsMember: [groups],
  status: boolean
}

group {
  name: string,
  members: [user],
  status: boolean
}
```

I am trying to remove a user document from group user array, when the user status is set to false.

Here is what I have done so far

```
return User.findOneAndUpdate(
  {_id: id},
  {$set: {status: false}},
  {new: true, useFindAndModify: false}
)
  .exec()
  .then(async (user) => {
    // return await Group.find({'_id': {$in: user.groupAsMember}})
    //   .then(group => {
    //     console.log(group)
    //   })
    return await Group.updateMany(
      {'_id': {$in: user.groupAsMember}},
      // {$pull: {"members.$._id": user._id}},
      // {$pull: {"member._id": {$eq: user.id}}}
      {$pull: {"members.id": user._id}},
      {new: true, useFindAndModify: false}
    )
      .then((user) => {
        console.log(user);
        return user;
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        return err;
      })
  })
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

As you can see the codes I commented, I have tried different solutions that I found online.
But I keep getting error such as

```
Cannot use the part (id) of (members.id) to traverse the element ({members: [ ObjectId('5f985ffc59355439ac59598e'), ObjectId('5f9a328c83eb44243021d756') ]})

unknown top level operator: $eq

The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query.
```

Please help me out if you know the answer.
Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this if you have not.It should work for you:

```
 { $pull: { members: { _id: { $eq: user._id } } } }
```

Also if you are using async await then you don't need to write `.then` because await will always return promise. So it should be

```
    return await Group.updateMany(
      {'_id': {$in: user.groupAsMember}},
      { $pull: { members: { _id: { $eq: user._id } } } }
      {new: true }
    )
```

Comment: thank you for your comment, I have tried it. but it does not work,,,although i get this message ```{ n: 2, nModified: 2, ok: 1 }```. seems like it is recognizing what i am trying. but in the actual document in database, there is no change...

Comment: I think there is typo error in my answer. Please replace member with members and then check

Comment: now it says ```user { n: 0, nModified: 0, ok: 1 }```. but i believe you are right, it should be members though....

Comment: sorry it still says ```{ n: 2, nModified: 2, ok: 1 }``` but does not change the database documents...

Comment: I have updaed my answer. Please try that.